# Firestore Nested Documents with random ID inside a collection document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an application using Angular and firebase. Where I want to create a collection called PETS inside that collection the document ID will be currently logged in users UID. And inside that Document I want to create documents with random IDs based on my Form values.

```
-|pets
   -|userId
        -|RandomId which contains all the form values
        -|RandomId which contains all the form values
```

Right Now I am using this method. Please tell me what are the changes that I need to make here. This method creating a collection with same ID as current users. But it's not creating separate documents inside the parent Document with users ID. Also I want to loop over those documents with random Ids and will show a list of PETS in fronted.

```
addPet(ownerName, PetName, type, breed, size){
    let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    if (user) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.afs.collection("pets").doc(user.uid).set({
          OwnerName: ownerName,
          Petname: PetName,
          PetType: type,
          PetBreed: breed,
          PetSize: size
        })
        .then((response) => {
            resolve(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error)
        });
      })
    } else {
        alert('user not logged in')
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can't nest documents immediately under other documents.  You'll need to use a named subcollection under the uid document for that, then add documents to that subcollection.

Comment: For the subcollection what are modifications I need to make in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you wish to store a user's pets at `/pets/userId`. To add each pet at this location, you would need to use a subcollection as documents can't hold other documents. The following code adds a pet that will be stored at `/pets/userId/pets/somePetId`.

```js
addPet(ownerName, petName, type, breed, size){
    let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    if (!user) {
      return Promise.reject({code: 'unauthenticated', message: 'user not logged in'})
    }
    return this.afs.collection("pets").doc(user.uid).collection("pets").add({
        OwnerName: ownerName,
        OwnerID: user.uid,
        PetName: petName,
        PetType: type,
        PetBreed: breed,
        PetSize: size
      });
  }
```

However you have two other ways you could model this data.

#### Global Pets Collection

Instead of saving pets under a `userId`, instead each pet has their own ID and you link that pet to their owner's ID.

```js
addPet(ownerName, petName, type, breed, size){
    let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    if (!user) {
      return Promise.reject({code: 'unauthenticated', message: 'user not logged in'})
    }
    return this.afs.collection("pets").add({
        OwnerName: ownerName,
        OwnerID: user.uid,
        PetName: petName,
        PetType: type,
        PetBreed: breed,
        PetSize: size
      });
  }
```

To get the an array of pets for a given user, you would use the following:

```js
function getPetsForCurrentUser() {
  let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
  if (!user) {
    return Promise.reject({code: 'unauthenticated', message: 'user not logged in'})
  }
  return this.afs.collection("pets").where("OwnerID", '==', user.uid).get()
    .then(childrenAsArrayOfObjects)
}
```

#### Pets Subcollection of User

Because you are using Cloud Firestore and not the Realtime Database, you can save each pet as a subcollection of the owner's user data. Unlike the Realtime Database, when you fetch the data of `/users/userId`, you only get the data of that specific document and not all the data nested under that path. The code below assigns each pet their own ID and saves it to a subcollection of it's owner:

```js
addPet(ownerName, petName, type, breed, size){
    let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
    if (!user) {
      return Promise.reject({code: 'unauthenticated', message: 'user not logged in'})
    }
    return this.afs.collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("pets").add({
        OwnerName: ownerName,
        OwnerID: user.uid,
        PetName: petName,
        PetType: type,
        PetBreed: breed,
        PetSize: size
      });
  }
```

To get the an array of pets for a given user, you would use the following:

```js
function getPetsForCurrentUser() {
  let user = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
  if (!user) {
    return Promise.reject({code: 'unauthenticated', message: 'user not logged in'})
  }
  return this.afs.collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("pets").get()
    .then(childrenAsArrayOfObjects)
}
```

With this data structure, if you wanted to query all pets, regardless of their owner, you would make use of a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

```js
let ragdollCatsQuery = db.collectionGroup('pets').where('PetType', '==', 'Cat').where('PetBreed', '==', 'Ragdoll');
ragdollCatsQuery.get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    console.log("Found " + querySnapshot.size + " cats with the breed: Ragdoll");
  })
```

#### Other Notes

Please use a consistent casing style to prevent errors and typos. e.g. Change `Petname` to `PetName` to match the database key `OwnerName`'s TitleCase. Similarly, the convention is to use camelCase for variable names, so the variable `PetName` should be `petName`.

The above functions both use the following transformation function:

```js
function childrenAsArrayOfObjects(querySnapshot, idFieldName) {
  let idFieldName = (idFieldName && idFieldName + "") || "id";
  let children = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach(childDoc => {
    children.push({...childDoc.data(), [idFieldName]: childDoc.id})
  }
  return children;
}
```

If you wanted to use a different field name for the document ID when using this transformation, you would use:

```js
.then(querySnapshot => childrenAsArrayOfObjects(querySnapshot, "PetID"))
```

You can find other transforms [here](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/09f91fd89fbd1bf4fdc14cdd1c94aaef).

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like this example. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/managing-firebase-user-relationships-to-database-records.

Comment: @RahulKundu The linked video is practices for the Realtime Database. The advice given doesn't completely apply to Cloud Firestore. I'd recommend looking at [Model Relational Data in Firestore NoSQL](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-nosql-data-modeling-by-example/) instead.

Comment: I've also updated this answer with some more details

Comment: This is fantastic. I will go with the global pet collection then a single pet will be linked to their owners. According to the owner if he is logged in then I will show pets only related to him. For that I will use use the query that you have mentioned.

Comment: Also I need one help. Can you please help me with the firebase Rolebased auth. In my application i have three roles admin employee and user. Based on their roles I want to show hide some parts of the ui

Comment: @RahulKundu That's best asked as a separate question, but if you want to discuss it, message me on the [Firebase Slack](https://firebase.community).

Comment: Ok I will text you there.

Comment: i am using Global Pets Collection technique. I am getting the result in console but when I am trying to use ngfor I can not see anything in the view. I have just posted a question regarding the issue.